# Problems in deleting a temp variable in dynamically allocated linked stack in c++

Tags: c++, stack

I just learnt about linked stacks and was coding one, by using a struct for nodes and a class 'menu' that houses all the functions like push, pop or display. I used a dynamically allocated 'tmp' node(not declared as a class variable) in those functions whenever needed. After I was done coding the function I 'delete'-d the 'tmp' and exited. But this is resulting in garbage values in my stack, though I am assured that the operations are otherwise working fine.

When I changed the dynamic alloc to static alloc of the 'tmp', my code worked fine, assuring that the other aspects of the code is correct. I even tried clearing the "delete tmp;" statements inside the push() and disp() and then also interestingly my code worked alright. I was instructed by my teachers at school that one should always 'delete' the mem allocated by 'new' operator to save mem leaks but I am confused so as to why the prevention itself is causing problems.

```
struct st //creating the stack nodes

{

 int n;

st *nxt;

};

class menu //houses push(),pop(),disp()

{

 st *top;

 public:

  menu() 

  {

   top=NULL;

   top->nxt=NULL;

  }

  void push(); //pushes new elements into stack

  void pop(); //pops out elements from top of stack

  void disp(); //displays the entire stack

  ~menu();

};


void menu::disp()

 {

  st *tmp=new st; //dynamically allocated node


  if(top==NULL)

   cout<<"Empty stack";

  else

  {

   cout<<"The new stack is";

   tmp=top;

   while(tmp!=NULL)

    {

     cout<<tmp->n<<" -> ";

     tmp=tmp->nxt;

    }

  }

  delete tmp; // deleting the dynamic mem

 }



void menu::push()

 {

  st *tmp= new st; //dynamically allocated node

  cout<<"Enter the new element";

  cin>>tmp->n;

  tmp->nxt=NULL;

  if(tmp==NULL)

   cout<<"Overflow";

  else if(top==NULL)

   {
    top=tmp;
   }
  else
   {
    tmp->nxt=top;
    top=tmp;

   }
  delete tmp; // deleting the dynamic mem
 }

void menu::pop()
 {
  cout<<"Deleting the top elememt"<<endl;
  if(top==NULL)
   cout<<"Underflow"<<endl;
  else
   {
    cout<<"The deleted element is   "<<top->n<<endl;
    top=top->nxt;
   }
 }

menu::~menu()
 {
  st *tmp= new st;

  while(top!=NULL)
   {
    tmp=top;
    top=top->nxt;
    delete tmp;
   }
 }
```

My logic is correct and it was proved when I used static mem alloc (or deleting the "delete tmp;") so acc to me it should work with dynamic mem alloc as well. But compiler keeps on feeding garbage values to my stack apart from the ones I entered.

I have an idea that I am allocating a mem space to 'tmp' at first but then I am bringing it into the already built stack and at the end I am deleting it when it becomes null. So in one sense I am not deleting the mem it was originally allocated. But if this is so then is it true that one can never use a dynamically alloc pointer as a temp variable? Because then one can never delete the mem without pre-storing the address in another static ptr. I feel this to be very crippling as I can't see any possible solution to the problem.

Any help on this matter and an easy to understand insight into dynamic pointers(alloc and dealloc) is welcome.

Comment: Research smart pointers.

Comment: You have this statement `st *tmp = new st` at the start of almost every function. You are allocating memory to `tmp` when you just need `tmp` to traverse the linked list.

Comment: The general rule of thumb when it comes to `new` is [use it only when you're forced to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new).

Comment: Future bug: `menu` violates [The Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Well its true that 'tmp' could've been made a class variable and hence no need to fuss about alloc and dealloc of mem. But neither logically or syntactically is it incorrect. Also I learnt the thumb rule at school, and hence I purposely deleted the 'tmp' and actually my code works perfectly well without that statement. But I am still unclear so as to what is causing the garbage output? None of these comments provide an insight to the problem from the computers point of view